# Magento add Custom order status

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sales

how to add these order status in order view page

Order Status:

**Pending**
**Approve**
**Processing**
**Invoice**
**Shipment**
**Complete**
Staus

Comment: you want to add button for that?

Comment: you need 
1)Pending Approve - New Order
2)Processing Invoice - at Invoice
3)Shipment Complete - at shipment

Comment: I need a button Pending for new order , Process for order , Invoice for order, shipement for order and complete for order

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Magento Order status under:

```
Admin -> System -> Order Status
```

Here you can create a new Status, in this case `Invoice` and then assign that status to the processing state (in this case).

Comment: Actually I need a button Pending for new order , Process for order , Invoice for order, shipement for order and complete for order

Comment: Then you need to write a module to inject the buttons into the "header" of the order and the according module code in order to process accordingly. Looking again at your question, I answered it as asked, as it didn't mentioned anything about buttons. And the bold bit is all on one line so I misread it…